# Order the results after counting them PHP

Tags: php, mysql, count

This code works great but I'm lost on how to order it.

**Example output:**

Hits 3 Mozilla Firefox 
Hits 2 Google Chrome 
Hits 4 Internet Explorer 
Hits 2 Apple Safari 
Hits 1 Opera

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM WEB_STATS WHERE real_user NOT LIKE 'Bot'");
$duplicates = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $results = $row['user_browser'];

if (!array_key_exists($results, $duplicates)) {
    $browsersLive[] = $results;
    $duplicates[$results] = 1; ## mark that we've already output this records
    }
    }

foreach($browsersLive as $browserswive){
    $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM WEB_STATS WHERE user_browser = '$browserswive'";
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die("Sorry, didn't work" . mysql_error());
    $browser_count = mysql_result($result, 0);

    if($browserswive == "Mozilla Firefox"){
    echo '<img alt="FireFox" height="32" src="images/fox-icons.png" width="32">Hits '.$browser_count.' '.$browserswive.'<br>';
}
    elseif($browserswive == "Internet Explorer"){
    echo '<img alt="Internet Explore" height="32" src="images/ie-icons.png" width="31">Hits '.$browser_count.' '.$browserswive.'<br>';
}
    elseif($browserswive == "Google Chrome"){
    echo '<img alt="Google Chrome" height="32" src="images/chrome-icons.png" width="32">Hits '.$browser_count.' '.$browserswive.'<br>';
}
    elseif($browserswive == "Apple Safari"){
    echo '<img alt="Apple Safari" height="32" src="images/safari-icons.png" width="32">Hits '.$browser_count.' '.$browserswive.'<br>';
}
    elseif($browserswive == "Opera"){
    echo '<img alt="Opera " height="33" src="images/opera-icons.png" width="33">Hits '.$browser_count.' '.$browserswive.'<br>';
}
}
```

Comment: How do you want to see it ordered?  Is the output example multiple columns or a single string?

Comment: I want the hits to run in descending order. The example output above is how it displays now.

Answer (score 1):

Tweak the SQL to

```
SELECT user_browser, COUNT(*) as hits
FROM WEB_STATS 
WHERE real_user!='Bot'      <-- replace the NOT LIKE 'Bot'
GROUP BY user_browser
ORDER BY hits DESC;
```

And you just need to query once, then iterate the results

Comment: Thanks for the "real_user!='Bot'" but I dont have **hits** to order by. If I did I wouldnt need to count. Unless Im missing something

Answer (score 0):

Try ordering something like:

- SUBSTRING_INDEX(colName,2)               -->  HITS 2 Opera  ===> HITS 2
- SUBSTRING(,INSTR(' ',colName))    -->  HITS 2 ==> 2
- CAST( AS SIGNED)                  -->  Convert 2 to number

Putting it all together

```
ORDER BY CAST(substring(substring_index(colName,2),INSTR(' ',colName)) AS SIGNED)
```

That should do what you are looking for...